# Can we swap the endianness of a data buffer, which is a fixed sized array, before mapping it to its eventual data structure?

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

**Scenario:** A remote machine (big endian) sends a message to a local machine (little endian) over RS422.

The local machine gets the message as a buffer, i.e. `dataBuffer` which is an array of 4 16-bit ints. This buffer data eventually be mapped to a `MainType` data somewhere in the program but this is not our concern. We need a function that swaps the bytes (change the endianness) using the `swapData()` method.

**Question:** Given the fact that `MainType` has exactly `4` data members each `16 bits` AND `dataBuffer` is array of size 4 and each data is 16 bits, can we just swap the data in the buffer WITHOUT mapping it to `MainType` data structure (as below)?

**Constraints:**

- The `dataBuffer`  needs to be global in the program,
- Swapping needs to be taken care of in `swapData()` function,
- The `data` will be filled in some other method such as `useData()`

Here is the code:

```
... 

typedef unsigned short int USINT16;

typedef struct { 
    USINT16  a : 1; 
    USINT16  b : 1; 
    USINT16  c : 1;                         
    USINT16  d : 1;                              
    USINT16  e : 1;  
    USINT16  f : 1;  
    USINT16  g : 1; 
    USINT16  h : 2;                                
    USINT16  i : 3;
    USINT16  j : 4; 
} OtherType; // 16 bits

typedef struct {   
    USINT16   X;
    USINT16   Y;
    USINT16   Z;
    OtherType W;  
} MainType;

...

unsigned short dataBuffer[4]; // available in global scope

...

void swapData() {
    receiveData(&dataBuffer); // data buffer is filled

    int i;  
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        dataBuffer[i] = __builtin_bswap16(dataBuffer);
    }
    // The data is little endian now ?
}

...

void useData() {
    MainType data; // map the swapped buffer to data

    // use the data etc.
    ....
}
```

Comment: There are endian-ness issues (big-little) that occur independently at the byte/word and bit level  (`USINT16  a : 1;  USINT16  b : 1;`).  This code is not portable.

Comment: @chux: What if I create a local data of MainType => map the buffer to it => perform byte swapping => write the data back to buffer?

Comment: erol yeniaras,   @Nominal Animal is on the right track.  For portability, avoid bit_fields.  Also consider [fixed width types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30942107/2410359) like `uint16_t` instead of `USINT16`.

Comment: @chux: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately I am not authorized to decide the usage of bit_fields and fixed width types (although I totally agree with you on that), since I am a contributor to a big system where the data structures have already been defined.

Comment: @erolyeniaras: what about the serial protocol? can you specify it precisely? Is the device frozen, ie will the code in it ever change?

Comment: @chqrlie: the code will no change. Serial connection is RS422.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote machine behavior is frozen, you can investigate and determine what is the encoding of bit-fields on that platform and translate the buffer received on the local machine appropriately.

Byte swapping all 16 bit entries, including `W`, is a good initial step, you might have to change the `struct` definition for `OtherType` to fit the order in which it is defined by the compiler for the remote machine.  You can determine that by transmitting samples from the remote machine where only 1 field is set to all bits one and the others stay 0 and print the 16 bit value received.

Byte-swapping `W` is advisable because `W.h` most likely falls on a byte boundary with 1 bit in each byte.  For its bits to be adjacent in the local machine, the bytes in `W` should be swapped.  If the bit order on the remote machine is `a b c d e f g h1 h0 i2 i1 i0 j3 j2 j1 j0` for the whole 16 bit word in `W`, when stored in memory on the remote machine, it becomes `<a b c d e f g h1>` `<h0 i2 i1 i0 j3 j2 j1 j0>` and subsequently transmitted as bytes and loaded in a 16 bit register on the local machine, it would become `h0 i2 i1 i0 j3 j2 j1 j0 a b c d e f g h1` if you **dont** swap the bytes, because the first byte is loaded in the low order bits of the register.  Byte swapping prevents this but you still may have a problem with the bit-field order in the local machine as your current definition might be encoded as `j3 j2 j1 j0 i2 i1 i0 h1 h0 g f e d c b a` if the bit-fields are likely allocated from the lowest to the highest bit positions.

If you know some assembly language, generate the assembly for code that manipulate the bit-fields on both platforms and check if the fields are placed differently.

Comment: Nice answer! Unfortunately, I can't change the structs. Byte-swapping first 3x16 bytes from for mapping them to X, Y, Z respectively can be enough for them. However, I am confused with W since it has bitfields. Let`s assume that they are filled to buffer in the order they appear in the struct. In other words, buffer has the last 16 bytes of the buffer in this order: 'a b c d e f g h h i i i j j j j'. 16 bit swap will give  'h i i i j j j j a b c d e f g h' , which messes up the order of the data since on the local machine I am still expecting the data in the same order (Am I terribly wrong?)

Comment: I updated the answer, but you are mistaken, I am quite confident you need to both a byte swap and a different definition for `OtherType` in the local machine with the bitfields in reverse order.