# Overflow behaviour of fast types from stdint.h

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c99

C99 and C++11 (and before them POSIX) introduced `least` and `fast` types in the `stdint` header, e.g. `int_fast16_t` or `uint_fast8_t`.

I wonder what guarantees of the overflow behaviour of these types are given. If these are the same as for "normal" integer types (so that unsigned types wrap around on overflow), I wonder how `uint_fast8_t` can actually be mapped to any different type than the fixed-witdh `uint8_t` type, and thus be faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "int" and "int\_fast16\_t"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942107/whats-the-difference-between-int-and-int-fast16-t)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck there is no word overflow mentioned in that question or the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C11 n1570 says that the

> The typedef name
>   `int_fastN_t`
>   designates the fastest signed integer type with a width
>   of **at least
>   N**
>   .  The typedef name
>   `uint_fastN_t`
>   designates the fastest unsigned integer
>   type with a width of **at least
>   N**
>   .

---

Thus no behaviour is guaranteed as such; what these say is that `int_fastN_t` must not have signed overflow in the range `2^(n-1) - 1` ... `2^(n-1) - 1`; `uint_fastN_t` must not have a wraparound for values less than `2^n - 1`. If you need a more exact wraparound behaviour, then do not use the fast types, and instead use the exact width types (aka `intN_t` and `uintN_t`).

Answer (score 1):

The overflow rules are the same as for any signed/unsigned integer variable.

`uint_fast16_t` is mapped to the fastest size that is at least 16 bits. If the fastest size happens to be 32 bits on a platform then the behaviour would be different. Consider:

```
uint_fast16_t k = 1 << 16;

if (k == 0) {
    printf("k is 16 bits\n");
} else {
    printf("k is larger than 16 bits\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If these are the same as for "normal" integer types (so that unsigned types wrap around on overflow)

The guarantees are exactly the same. Signed integers will overflow, and unsigned will wrap around. The maximum value that can be represented depends on which integer type the the type is an alias of.

> I wonder how uint_fast8_t can actually be mapped to any different type than the fixed-witdh uint8_t type

It can be an alias of any unsigned integer type that is at least 8 bits wide.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how `uint_fast8_t` can actually be mapped to any different type than the fixed-width `uint8_t` type, and thus be faster.

Firstly, there doesn't have to *be* a `uint8_t` type.  On a 36-bit word addressed machine (they have existed), a `char` would probably be 9 bits wide. (*Word addressed* means that the natural way to access memory is in *words* (of some size).  Addressing sub-sections of a word requires shifting and masking, and pointers which address such sub-sections need additional bits to refer to the sub-unit within the word.)

On such a machine, the compiler author would have the interesting decision as whether to make `uint_fast8_t` be the same as `unsigned char` (9 bits) or the 36-bit `unsigned int` type.

As others have said, there will be an implementation defined maximum of these types, and if you exceed that limit the unsigned types will wrap and the signed types will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: On a word-addressed machine `sizeof(int)` may reasonably be `1`, making `char` have as many bits as the word. You *could* make `char` smaller and use masking/shifting in the past, but today you'd want multi-processor machines, and C11's guarantees for atomic access to objects make masking/shifting impractical.

Comment: That's another plausible implementation, yes.  (The PDP 10 of course wasn't multi-core.)