# Why INT_FAST16_MAX is defined as INT32_MAX (VS 2015)?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I opened **"stdint.h"** file from **visual studio 2015** and as shown in below image, I noticed the `INT_FAST16_MAX` is defined to `INT32_MAX`. And same with unsigned too. Why is it so?

[image]

But the least ones are defined as expected. (below)

```
#define INT_LEAST16_MAX  INT16_MAX
#define UINT_LEAST16_MAX UINT16_MAX
```

Comment: Because int_fast16_t is the same as int32_t?

Comment: Because the sizes are implementation-#define'd.

Comment: Why not? On this platform `int32_fast_t` just happens to be the same as `int32_t`. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`INT_FAST16_MAX` is the largest value that can be stored in an `int_fast16_t` variable.

`int_fast16_t` is guaranteed to be the fastest int with a size of *at least* 16 bits.

Because MSVC is targeting machines that have 32-bit general purpose registers which are faster to access than 16-bit, `int_fast16_t` is actually a 32-bit integer. And thus, `INT_FAST16_MAX` is `INT32_MAX`.

See also:

- [What's the difference between "int" and "int_fast16_t"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30942107/119527)