What exactly is a 'fast' integer?
How are uint_fast32_t, int_fast8_t different from uint_least32 and int_least8_t or uint32_t or int8_t?
I've looked through countless answers but never really got the gist of it. A simple and concise answer would be appreciated.

another one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8500761/6266506

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593541/why-are-the-fast-integer-types-faster-than-the-other-integer-types, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942107/whats-the-difference-between-int-and-int-fast16-t

fast and least types might be useful on systems that don't have uint32_t or int8_t. So you will probably never have a reason to use them in C++.

Think of it as giving compilers your "intent": uint32_t  says "I want 32 bits, precisely. Not 33 bits, please". uint_fast32_t says "I just want at least 32 bits, and please give me something that's really fast" while uint_least32_t says "I want at least 32 bits, and please make it small". This is mostly interesting for systems that can't give you 32 bit precisely. Or maybe they are totally optimized for 64 bits, so processing a 32 bit value would have them spend an extra clock tick to expand it to 64 bits first.

Those fast and least types are just a simple way to write portable code when a minimum bitness is needed. The other fixed-width integer types are optional, but fast and least types are required to be present in all architectures.

fast depends on the hardware.
